# Stored procedure WHERE clause error (expects parameter)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_twa_report1]
    (@date1 as DATE,
     @date2 as DATE,
     @Filter1 as INT,
     @Kheadoption as NVARCHAR(10),
     @Kcodeoption as NVARCHAR(10),
     @Ktypeoption as NVARCHAR(10),
     @Shiftoption as INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        wageentry.empno, wageentry.kdate, wageentry.kcode,
        empmain.paybookno, 
        kamjaricode.kdesc, kamjarihead.khead, kamjarihead.khdesc,
        wageentry.shiftno
    INTO
        #tmpTbl1
    FROM
        wageentry, empmain, kamjaricode, kamjarihead
    WHERE 
        wageentry.empno = empmain.empno
        AND wageentry.kcode = kamjaricode.kcode
        AND kamjaricode.khead = kamjarihead.khead
        AND wageentry.kdate >= @date1 AND wageentry.kdate <= @date2
        AND (wageentry.shiftno = CASE @Shiftoption 
                                     WHEN 1 THEN 1 
                                     WHEN 2 THEN 1 
                                     WHEN 3 THEN 2 
                                     ELSE 5 
                                 END
             OR wageentry.shiftno = CASE @Shiftoption 
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 2 
                                        WHEN 2 THEN 1 
                                        WHEN 3 THEN 2 
                                        ELSE 5 
                                    END
            OR wageentry.shiftno = CASE @Shiftoption
                                       WHEN 1 THEN 5  
                                       WHEN 2 THEN 1 
                                       WHEN 3 THEN 2 
                                       ELSE 5 
                                   END)
        AND ((@Kheadoption IS NULL) OR (kamjaricode.khead = @Kheadoption))
        AND ((@Kcodeoption IS NULL) OR (kamjaricode.kcode = @Kcodeoption))
        AND ((@Ktypeoption IS NULL) OR (kamjaricode.ktype = @Ktypeoption))

    -- More code here

End
```

The above stored procedure works fine from Management Studio, but when I run it from my Winforms app, I get an error:

> Procedure or function 'sp_twa_report1' expects parameter '@Kheadoption', which was not supplied.

The parameters `@Kheadoption, @Kcodeoption, @Ktypeoption` are null as default. So from my understanding those lines of the query should be ignored. Where am I going wrong?

My Winforms code is:

```
commandText = "sp_twa_report1";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, cs);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = mySdate;
command.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.Date).Value = myEdate;
command.Parameters.Add("@Filter1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Filter1;
command.Parameters.Add("@Kheadoption",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Kheadoption;
command.Parameters.Add("@Kcodeoption", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Kcodeoption;
command.Parameters.Add("@Ktypeoption", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Ktypeoption;
command.Parameters.Add("@Shiftoption", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myShiftno;
        
cs.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(dt);
cs.Close();
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`DBNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=net-5.0) instead of `null`? It appears that, that should be [sent instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#deriving-parameter-information) of an actual null value.

Comment: You get the error even when all the parameters has values?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: `... END ((@Ktypeoption IS NULL) OR (kamjaricode.ktype = @Ktypeoption))`? Seems like a typo.

Comment: Also, you should schema qualify objects when using them. i.e.: You should invoke `dbo. sp_twa_report1` instead of just `sp_twa_report1` because the logged in user may have a different default schema that doesn't contain a `sp_twa_report1` stored procedure or has one with a different set of parameters.

Comment: A second also, you should use the `Add(String, SqlDbType, Int32)` version of the method to specify the length of your string parameters, e.g.: `Add("@Kheadoption",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = Kheadoption;` In its current state may be defaulting to `@Kheadoption nvarchar(1)` which doesn't match the parameter specified in the stored procedure signature.

Comment: DBNull instead of null is working. Thankyou @DekuDesu. command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kheadoption", Kheadoption == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : Kheadoption);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kcodeoption", Kcodeoption == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : Kcodeoption);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ktypeoption", Ktypeoption == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : Ktypeoption);

Comment: @marc_s Yes I need to learn INNER OUTER joins. Its more powerful. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

> The parameters @Kheadoption, @Kcodeoption, @Ktypeoption are null as default. So from my understanding those lines of the query should be ignored.

Consider using [`DBNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=net-5.0) instead of `null` when passing parameters for a stored procedure.

[Per MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#deriving-parameter-information): When you send a null parameter value to the server, you must specify DBNull, not `null`.